# magento custom email template send order details

Tags: magento

How can I send order details in my custom mail template. I have tried
`{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}` in my template. I have replaced `var order` with `$order` (loaded order with increment id).

The generated email is displaying the billing address but not the order details.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to go log in Admin Panel of Magento.
Go to System -> Transaction Emails.
Load the new order template and make changes there instead of custom email template for new order.

Comment: There is no need to copy. Just create a new template in admin by loading the default template.

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745490/edit-magento-email-template   will also hep you.

Comment: What I want to do is when any update in order takes place i want to send email..so far nothing seems to be working